# How to configure jboss 7 to write logs to different folder

Tags: java, logging, jboss7.x

I'm using Jboss 7.1.1 and I have the following log definition:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <size-rotating-file-handler name="ACEII">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%z{utc}%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="ACEII.log"/>
            <rotate-size value="10M"/>
            <max-backup-index value="10"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </size-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="ace2" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="ACEII"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
    </subsystem>
```

I'd like the ACE log to be written to a different folder, so I tried putting different values in the relative-to attribute but nothing seems to work, any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer :)

I'm using Java service wrapper to install Jboss as a windows service and that service has a configuration file located in a certain path, so I've noticed that if i remove the relative-to attribute it write the logs to the folder where the configuration file is located.

All i had to do define it like this:

```
<size-rotating-file-handler name="ACEII">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%z{utc}%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            **<file path="../Log/ACEII.log"/>**
            <rotate-size value="10M"/>
            <max-backup-index value="10"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </size-rotating-file-handler>
```

And that did the trick for me.

Comment: This is quite what you were asking though. Also the behavior you're seeing is not guaranteed. The "../" could go somewhere else other than the configuration directory.

Answer (score 6):

You need to leave off the `relative-to` and enter the absolute path in the `path` attribute.

```
    <size-rotating-file-handler name="ACEII">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%z{utc}%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <file path="/var/log/myLogDir/ACEII.log"/>
        <rotate-size value="10M"/>
        <max-backup-index value="10"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </size-rotating-file-handler>
```

You can also use your own relative path by adding a path to your configuration.

In CLI you would just execute: `/path=my.log.dir:add(path="/var/log")`

If you just want to edit the xml add the following.

```
<paths>
    <path name="my.log.dir" path="/var/log"/>
</paths>
```

Paths themselves can have a relative path if you wanted to define specif directories in a default log directory for example.

Once you have your path defined you can use the name you gave the path in the `relative-to` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, but absolute path is not good enough as you can imagine, and I tried it with environment variable but with no success. Is there a way to define my own path like 'jboss.server.log.dir' so i can set the 'relative-to' to that path? I tried using 'wrapper.app.parameter' and 'wrapper.java.additional' to define this path but with no success (I'm using the java wrapper service)

Comment: See above. I added instructions on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks again, this is indeed a progress towards what I need, but again, it does not seem to allow Env. variables.

Comment: You can use any system property and add substitution in the file path as follows

<file path="${myserverlog.dir}/server.log"/>

Add a new system property "-Dmyserverlog.dir".

Answer (score 4):

This works just fine for me.

```
domain.sh -Djboss.server.log.dir="my custom logs dir"
```

Answer (score 2):

Know this is an older question, but still found it relevant for JBOSS EAP 7

I found James response from here insightful - https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/Wildfly82LogPathChange

I was able to edit the standalone.conf and specify the custom logging directory there.

The is also a domain.conf that can be edited for domain mode.

All that is needed it to add the following to the end of the file:

```
#Specify the log dir
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.server.log.dir=my custom logs dir"
```

As I understand it for Windows the .bat files can be updated instead of the .conf files.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use; I then handle log rotation with `logrotate`:

```
    <file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
        <append value="true"/>                                                                                                                             
    </file-handler>
```

Obviously, you can modify this to suit your needs.