# JBoss 7.1.1 does not create server.log

Tags: logging, dns, location, customization, jboss7.x

Here is what we currently have running,
JBoss 7.1.1 in Domain Mode.
OS Red Hat:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)

So on the host(Host-A) that acts as the Domain Controller we also have an App-Server. We have 17 other hosts but I am testing it out on Host-A right now.

In the domain.xml on that very server, we have created a custom profile and in that profile I have configured a log location like this:

```
<profile name="AppLogix-full-ha">
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
                <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                    <level name="INFO"/>
                    <formatter>
                        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                    </formatter>
                </console-handler>
                <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
                    <level name="INFO"/>
                    <formatter>
                        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                    </formatter>
                   <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="/apps/logs/AppLogix.Cluster/server.log"/>
                    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                    <append value="true"/>
                </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

and this the only place where the log is configured for the app server.
I don't have anything in the host.xml on Host-A.

Problem is it still keeps creating the log in  the /apps/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/domain/servers/AppLogix.Member1/log ( which *I THINK* is the default location)

What am I doing wrong here experts?
What did I miss?
Any help is monumentally appreciated.
Sincerely,
KK.

Comment: Have yout tryed to remove the "relative-to" part of the <file> tag?

Comment: you mean make it look like this?<file="jboss.server.log.dir" path="/apps/logs/AppLogix.Cluster/server.log"/>

Answer (score 0):

Remove the *relative-to* attribute. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9913943/846553) similar answer.

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
  ...
  <file path="/apps/logs/AppLogix.Cluster/server.log"/>
  ...
 </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

Comment: I just tried that and it didnt create the logs in the location.
Its still creating the logs under 
/apps/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/domain/servers/AppLogix.Member1/log

Here is my current confirguration in domain.xml

   <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
     <file path="/apps/logs/AppLogix.Cluster/server.log"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>

Any other ideas?

Comment: OK I figured it out....I was using the wrong profile at the end of the domain.xml

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out....I was using the wrong profile at the end of the domain.xml..........OK I figured it out
at the bottom of the domain.xml
All the profiles had the correct locations for the server.log file but there was another profile called full-ha( an un-used useless profile) that will still pointing to the default location. I forgot to change it from full-ha to appropriate profile name
Once I changed it , it all worked fine !!!