# JBoss 7.2.0 Final creating server.log file in unexpected places

Tags: jboss7.x, centos6

I am trying to set up JBoss 7.2.0 Final on CentOS 6.5 to handle 4 different deployments of our software. I'm not sure if I have set things up correctly or not, but everything seems to work except that `server.log` is not ending up where I think I am telling it to be saved in 3 of 4 deployments.

There are 4 HTTP ports being used for the deployments. They are `:8080`, `:8180`, `:9876`, and `:9976`. I don't know if that is relevant information or not, but I bring it up because in each `standalone.xml` file I am using the `jboss.socket.binding.port-offset` option to assign the ports. The only deployment that seems to work flawlessly is `:8080`, which has `jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0`. `:8180` has `jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:100`, etc.

Each deployment lives in its own directory, for example

```
/opt/jboss-eap-6.1/target/standalone8080/
```

and

```
/opt/jboss-eap-6.1/target/standalone9876/
```

In the `standalone.xml` file for each deployment (`/opt/jboss-eap-6.1/target/standalone9876/configuration/standalone.xml`, for example), the server log is specified in the same way:

```
<file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
```

This should result in the server.log being saved in, for example,
`/opt/jboss-eap-6.1/target/standalone9876/log`,
and when redeploying the software on each port, I have echoed out the `$JBOSS_LOG_DIR` variable and it seems on the surface to be set correctly in each case.

**However**, as mentioned above, *only* port `:8080` creates the `server.log` file in the expected location (`/opt/jboss-eap-6.1/target/standalone8080/log`).

**The incorrect locations:**

--Port `:8180` puts its `server.log` file in the `:8080` location. I.e., `:8180` overwrites the `server.log` file at `/opt/jboss-eap-6.1/target/standalone8080/log`.

--Port `:9876` puts its server.log file in `/opt/jboss-eap-6.1/target/standalone/log`. I.e., it creates a new folder simply called `standalone` and puts the file there. I will add that in a former time, the entire port `:9876` deployment lived in a folder at that path (`/opt/jboss-eap-6.1/target/standalone`). This apparent clue makes me think there is some other place where there is a setting for the `server.log` file path. I could be quite wrong.

--Finally, port `:9976` is putting its server.log file one level above the desired `log` directory, in other words, at `/opt/jboss-eap-6.1/target/standalone9976`.

I don't know if the way these 4 deployments are being handled is fundamentally incorrect or if there is a setting hiding somewhere that is overriding my desired paths.

I saw [one poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039755/jboss-7-1-1-does-not-create-server-log) with a similar problem say they made a change to `domain.xml` to fix the issue. I don't think I can do that, since I only have one `domain.xml` file (located in `/opt/jboss-eap-6.1/domain/configuration`)  that is associated with all 4 deployments.

[Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910571/how-to-configure-jboss-7-to-write-logs-to-different-folder/9913943#9913943) recommended removing the "relative-to" bit in the `<file>` tag in the `standalone.xml` file. I tried that with port `:9876` as follows:

```
<file path="/opt/jboss-eap-6.1/target/standalone9876/log/server.log"/>
```

This did not work for me. The server.log file still ended up in

```
<file path="/opt/jboss-eap-6.1/target/standalone/log/server.log"/>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Is there simply another place I need to declare my log path, or is the way these 4 servers are set up just plain incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at each `logging.properties` file in each configuration directory. You might just need to update those, once, to change the path to `{jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log`. Then when you start each server you'll need to specify the `jboss.server.log.dir` directory.

```
./bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.server.log.dir=$JBOSS_HOME/target/standalone8080/log
```

There might be a clever way to handle it in the `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf` file.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! Indeed, `logging.properties` for each deployment contained a hard-coded line like `handler.FILE.fileName=/opt/jboss-eap-6.1/target/standalone8080/log/server.log`. The paths were all different and all wrong except for the `server.log` in the `standalone8080` folder. I tried changing the path and calling `standalone.sh` using the `-D` option. The result was that the path substitution was not made, and `server.log` was created in a folder named `{jboss.server.log.dir}` in the directory `standalone.sh` was called from.

Comment: So, in the end I modified `logging.properties`, hard-coding in the correct paths for `server.log`. That will suffice until I learn more about JBoss. Again, thank you!

Comment: The `logging.properties` file will be overridden each time the server is booted. IIRC there is a JIRA to hopefully solve this issue, but we generally have a chicken and egg problem with when the `jboss.server.log.dir` property is set.

Comment: Good to know. I will keep an eye out for this particular issue in case the log files start winding up in strange places once more. Thanks again!